# Параллельное ручное тестирование android приложения

Tags: android, devops, android-testing

Всем привет!
Я хотел бы найти инструмент позволяющий запускать приложение на несколько устройствах, и когда я совершаю действие (допустим клик по кнопке), то это действие дублировалось на другое устройство.
Т.е я хочу сразу тестировать и проверять результат на различных версиях android и производителях, так как ожидаемый результат может отличаться.
И чтобы не тестировать на каждом устройстве по отдельности, я хотел бы совершать действия только на одном, а на все остальные устройства мои действия дублировались.

Подскажите знаком ли кто-нибудь с подобным инструментов.
(я лично видел подобный подход на каком-то эмуляторе, название не помню, но я ищу это для физического устройства)

Comment: Устройства будут одинаковые? Нужно чтобы совпадали архитектура+частота процессора, версия ОС, разрешение экрана, и даже размеры верхней/нижней плашек с состоянием и кнопками. да и вообще одинаковые настройки всего, иначе у вас будет рассинхрон.

Comment: нет. Цель как раз таки дублировать действия на различные устройства.

Но позвольте поинтересоваться, о каком инструменте речь?

Comment: Нет никакого инструмента, клики можно дублировать через adb, но нужны координаты куда кликать)

Comment: самое простое - пользоваться стандартным эмулятором из android studio. Что тут еще сказать))